# Python: Iterator returns None

Tags: python, class, iterator, generator, nonetype

Here is my code:

```
class Prizes(object):
    def __init__(self, purchases, n, d):
        self.p = purchases
        self.n = n
        self.d = d
        self.x = 1

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        print(self.x)

        if self.x % self.n == 0 and self.p[self.x - 1] % self.d == 0:
            self.x = self.x + 1
            return self.x - 1
        elif self.x > len(self.p):
            raise StopIteration

        self.x = self.x + 1

def superPrize(purchases, n, d):
  return list(Prizes(purchases, n, d))
```

An example of usage:

```
superPrize([12, 43, 13, 465, 1, 13], 2, 3)
```

The output should be:

```
[4]
```

But actual output is:

```
[None, None, None, 4, None, None].
```

Why does it happen?

Comment: Your problem is your implementation of `__next__`. When Python calls `__next__`, it will always expect a return value. However, in your case, it looks like you may no always have a return value each call. Thus, Python uses the default return value of a function - `None`.

Comment: What is the point of making this `Prizes` iterator?

Comment: Also, may I add, you did a nice job asking your first question here. You did everything correctly. You provided an [mcve], posted your expected output, and posted your actually out.  And because of this, you got (hopefully)  helpful answers. Congrats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is your implementation of `__next__`. When Python calls `__next__`, ***it will always expect a return value***. However, in your case, it looks like you may not always have a return value each call. Thus, Python uses the default return value of a function - `None`:

You need some way to keep program control inside of `__next__` until you have an actually return value. This can be done using a `while`-loop:

```
def __next__(self):
    while True:
        if self.x % self.n == 0 and self.p[self.x - 1] % self.d == 0:
            self.x = self.x + 1
            return self.x - 1
        elif self.x > len(self.p):
            raise StopIteration
        self.x = self.x + 1
```

Comment: May I ask why this was down-voted? I would genuinely appreciate it if the downvoter could share there concerns with my answer. Thank you.

Comment: I would guess because code-wise, it&#39;s an exact duplicate of a slightly older answer

Comment: I haven't downvoted (quite the opposite) but it could be because the code part is identical to the other answer. It's a good answer especially because it actually explains what is happening and why and not just a "here is the code" answer.

Comment: @MSeifert Eh, if that is the reason, guess I can't do much about it. I guess people just see identically code and down-vote. I actually was debating on posting an answer for a second because the other answer had the same code as mine, despite me having written the same code independently just a bit latter.

Comment: @Eric Yeah. I hate to say it but I figured that. I expanded a bit in my comment to MSeifert.

Comment: I'll just leave this here - the downvote you got is a byproduct of unhealthy rep-hunting. Btw, the first up vote you got was mine :-)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Well, figured as much. Just live and learn I guess ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. Thanks for the up-vote though, I appreciate it. Tryin' see if I can go ahead and break 10k, then I'll be satisfied...for a bit ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it with `while` so that your method doesn't return a value until you found one:

```
def __next__(self):
    while True:
        if self.x % self.n == 0 and self.p[self.x - 1] % self.d == 0:
            self.x = self.x + 1
            return self.x - 1
        elif self.x > len(self.p):
            raise StopIteration

        self.x = self.x + 1
```

Things working with iterators call `__next__` expecting it to return a value, but the method returns a value only under a condition, otherwise it reaches the end of the method and it returns `None`.